# How to optimize Queue Reconstruction by Height? (LeetCode)

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is the problem statement

Suppose you have a random list of people standing in a queue. Each person is described by a pair of integers (h, k), where h is the height of the person and k is the number of people in front of this person who have a height greater than or equal to h. Write an algorithm to reconstruct the queue.

Note:
The number of people is less than 1,100.

example:

```
Input:
[[7,0], [4,4], [7,1], [5,0], [6,1], [5,2]]

Output:
[[5,0], [7,0], [5,2], [6,1], [4,4], [7,1]]`
```

I've solved this by first sorting on height, then position so the input in the example becomes

```
[[4,4], [5,0], [5,2], [6,1], [7,0], [7,1]]
```

I also have a list of available indices and an empty array

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `[-, -, -, -, -, -]`

I iterate through the sorted array and use `k` to pick out the `kth` available index.  So our first iteration is `[4,4]` and we have all available indices, I will pop off the 4th index from available indices and place the `[4,4]` tuple in 4th index a new array.  My available indices and new array are now

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 5]`, `[-, -, -, -, [4,4], -]`

The next iteration is `[5,0]`.  I pop off the `0th` index from available indices which is `0` and place `[5,0]` in the `0th` index of the new array.

`[1, 2, 3, 5]`, `[[5,0], -, -, -, [4,4], -]`

The third iteration is `[5,2]`, this is different as the problem statement mentions that `k` refers to the number of people of the same height or taller so I keep an offset variable and previous height variable to track how many people are ahead of this person.  If the current person is the same height as the last person I will pop off the `k-1th` available index and increase the offset by .  If the next person is the same height as the previous 2 I will pop off the `k-2th` available index.  When a new height is seen, the offset is reset.

`[1, 3, 5]`, `[[5,0], -, [5,2], -, [4,4], -]`

and so on...

The algorithm I've written is below

```
def reconstructQueue(self, people: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
    people.sort(key=lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))
    n = len(people)
    recon = [0] * n
    available_idxs = list(range(n))
    previous_height = -1
    offset = 0
    for h, k in people:
        if previous_height == h:
            offset += 1
            position = available_idxs.pop(k-offset)
        else:
            offset = 0
            position = available_idxs.pop(k)
        previous_height = h
        recon[position] = [h, k]
    return recon
```

The complexity is `O(nlogn)` for the sort, and probably `O(n^2)` for `n` list pops so overall `O(n^2)`.  What changes can I make to optimize my solution?

Comment: I think your question could have a better audience in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: how do I move it over there?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89799/how-to-migrate-to-code-review

Comment: Your question is fine here under the algorithm tag

Comment: You should visit the `discuss` section for that question in Leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/queue-reconstruction-by-height/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query= That is the best you can get. The question is valid here as well. Someone can post here BIT solution for you here. But in the discuss section, you'll find multiple solutions in various languages with varying complexities. That is the best way to learn there.